# How to populate a DIV with AJAX and make it visible

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to populate a div with the results of user actions on another div via an AJAX call so only the 2nd div gets reloaded.  Currently the 2nd div never even becomes visible much less display that one test value. I know it is going into the Success block of the AJAX because of alerts I've used. So it is puzzling to say the least.

View:

```
 $(".Results").hide();

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submitButton").click(function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ControllerName/Results/",
                    data: {
                         ID: $('#ID').val(),
                          // other values
                        },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $(".Results").show();
                        $("#Results").html(data);
                   
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error")
                    }
                });
            });
      });   

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
 "SubmitForm"}))
 {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model, "ID", "Text"), "Choose")
     //other dropdown lists

   <input name="submitButton" type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit"/>
 }

 <div class="Results" id="Results">
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Sum)
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View(GetModel());
    }


   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Results(Model ViewModel, string ID, /*other values*/)
    {
       ViewModel.ID = ID;
       // other value assignments
       
       ViewModel.Sum = "test";
       
      return Json(ViewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

Comment: what does `data` has in it ? do `console.log(data)` inside ajax success function and see.

Comment: It has the object in it.  With the populated values.  It should have HTML right?

Comment: Do console and see onces exactly what it has .. Also are there any error showing in browser console ? Not sure about backend ..but your frontend seems okay to me .

Comment: I just did.  It has the object with the values.

Comment: If its json object then [parse](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) it and use in your dom .Also , how about checking with dummy value if this gets show  i.e:`$("#Results").html("something");`

Comment: Breaking into it,  I can see that data has the object and not the html.  I'm returning the Viewmodel...maybe I should be returning something else?

Comment: and when I put "something" it gets shown on the page as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222406/discussion-between-swati-and-john).